# Ask user if they want to change skills in OnInterruptDialogAsync

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

Currently I'm using the Virtual Assistant ( 4.x) framework. I'm having difficulties implementing a flow that would allow users to change Skills while they are in the middle of a particular skill. 
Meaning if they are in Skill A, if they trigger an Intent for Skill B I would like to ask them if they really want to go to Skill B or if they want to stay in Skill A. I currently have added code that enables be to see that a user triggered an intent for a different skill. What would be the best approach to ask for user input to see if the user really wants to move to a different skill while in the middle of another ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you think of your skills as complex dialogs instead of actual skills. That way, it should be relatively clear how to handle this type of interupption.

Personally, I'm a fan of waterfalls.

```
//FIRST
AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(STARTSKILLB), new WaterfallStep[]
{
    AskStepAsync,
    LoopStepAsync
}));

//LATER, ON CHECKING INTENTS

switch(intent)
{
    case "SkillA":
        await KEEPONSKILLA(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        break;
    case "SkillB":
        await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(STARTSKILLB), cancellationToken);
        break;

}


//THEN THIS
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var messageText = $"Would you like to go chill in Skill B?";
    var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
    }
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoopStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
    {
        //shift on over to skill  B
    }
    //End this dialog, routing back up to where you left off in Skill A
    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
}
```